# Dynamics 365 free up files storage space

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, power-platform

In the Power Platform admin center, Capacity tab, I see that the part "Files" takes a lot of space, and I would like to reduce it. I have checked:

- email attachments
- notes

but these are only responsible for a small part of the utilized storage. What else can be responsible for the "Files" part of the storage utilization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File and database: The following tables store data in file and database storage:
Attachment

AnnotationBase

Any custom or out-of-the-box table that has columns of datatype file or image (full size)

Any table that is used by one or more installed Insights applications and ends in - Analytics

WebResourceBase

RibbonClientMetadataBase

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/capacity-storage#capacity-page-details